# How to convert Key to String and vice versa

Tags: java, android, security, encryption

I'm very new to Java Security and hope you guys can do me a favor by providing solution for me. I have a method as stated below:

```
public Key keyGen() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{
    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
    keyGen.init(56);
    Key key = keyGen.generateKey();
    return key;
}
```

My objective is to convert this `Key` type value to either `byte[]` type or `String` type and of course, convert them back to `Key` type again for decryption purpose. What's the ideal solution available for me?

**P/S: This method will be implemented in Android Apps and `Key` value are to pass from activity to activity.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting Key to String and back to Key Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292389/converting-key-to-string-and-back-to-key-java)

Comment: Hi @Voicu, I'm not sure if the Key value generated would be the same as that post as I'm very new to this area.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079579/aes-algo-decryption-issue/17080884#17080884. check this if it helps

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks so much! My problem is solved! Appreciate much!

Answer (score 1):

Key has a getEncoded() method to convert to byte[]. Don't use String for this. String is not a container for binary data.

Comment: Hi @EJP, may I know how to convert it back to Key type again for decryption purpose?