# Encrypt the text using DES secret key in java

Tags: java, encryption, des

I am trying to make encryption and decryption program through DES. In this code section I am creating a secretKey

```
  Cipher desCipher;
  KeyGenerator keygenerator;
  SecretKey myDesKey; 
  try{
    keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
    myDesKey = keygenerator.generateKey();
    byte[] encoded = myDesKey.getEncoded();
    // convert secret key to string 
   String stringKey =Base64.encodeToString(myDesKey.getEncoded());

    // converting back from  string to secret key. 
    //its returning javax.crypto.spec.SecretKey object but i need com.sun.crypto.provider.DESKey object

   SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(stringKey.getBytes(), 0, stringKey.length(), "DES"); 
      String text="hello how are you " 
     desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
    byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());   

    System.out.println("text encrypted successfully");        

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
     {
       ex.printStackTrace();
     }

is throwing the exception
```

java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: (null)

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting Key to String and back to Key Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292389/converting-key-to-string-and-back-to-key-java)

Comment: look what i am asking what that question is returning and what i want

Answer (score 1):

You're converting the key to base-64, but not converting it back again.

Comment: The mistake is that you are converting the key to base-64 but not converting it back again.

Comment: how should i convert can you give example

Comment: BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
             byte[] encodedKey = decoder.decodeBuffer(keyvalue);
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey,0,encodedKey.length, "DES");  i have used this instead

Comment: Yes, base64-decoding would cure the mistake that you aren't base64-decoding. Is that what you're asking now?

Comment: even thats not working just look what is the diff between  KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();   and SecretKeySpec()

Comment: This exchange isn't making any sense. If you want an AES key why are you specifying DES? If all that's part of your question, edit it into your question. All your other comments here have been 100% redundant.